# What is the word for abdominal pain, stomach ache or belly ache?

Tags: word-choice, transatlantic-differences

In everyday conversation, what's the usual word that describes the abdominal pain that is caused by diarrhoea? Do you say it's a "stomach ache" or "belly ache"? Is there a difference between British and American English?

Comment: A medical term? One you'd use when telling your boss you're off sick? One to your friends? To a child?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my (American) experience, both stomach ache, belly ache, and additionally tummy ache are correct. However, stomache ache tends to sound more 'mature' and 'formal' than tummy/belly, which is usually associated with a more childish or informal tone.

Comment: Thank you, Connie!

Answer (score 0):

**(stomach) cramp(s)/cramping** (n.)

> **Stomach cramps**: A nonmedical term most often used to describe pain in the mid- or upper abdominal area.  [rxlist.com](https://www.rxlist.com/stomach_cramps/definition.htm)

**cramping**

> Abdominal pain or cramping may accompany diarrhea.
> [MedicalNewsToday.com](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/323852#:%7E:text=Abdominal%20pain%20or%20cramping%20may,irritable%20bowel%20syndrome%20(IBS).)

**cramp**

> Sharp abdominal pain —usually used in plural [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cramp)

Comment: If someone told me they have cramping or a cramp, I would immediately ask where? In what of your body? I suppose because I use English like the average Joe. And you aren't quoting all the M-W definitions of cramp.

Comment: @shumble Yes, you would specify "stomach" if it's not already understood (edited). // Correct, on ELU we generally quote only the relevant definition(s).

Comment: @shumble Yes, you could specify "stomach" if it's not already understood (edited). // No, on ELU we generally quote only the relevant definition(s) and m-w has this definition for *cramp,* not *stomach cramp*.